# How to record audio and playback on Ionic 2?

Tags: audio, typescript, ionic-framework, audio-recording, ionic2

I am currently working on an Ionic 2 app project which allows users to record their own sound, stop the recording and also play that sound back. According to ionic-native, I can see they provide 2 plugins which are MediaPlugin and MediaCapture. I have tried out using MediaPlugin but I faced problems while starting the record, stop it and play it back.
Have anybody experienced using this plugin ? I have went through the ionic docs and some other blogs but still I am not able to make it. I am very new to this, thank you so much for your efforts. I appreciate all of your idea.

Regards,

This is the logs I got from emulator while start the recording:

```
I/MPEG4Writer(  401): limits: 2147483647/0 bytes/us, bit rate: 12200 bps and the estimated moov size 3072 bytes
D/Genyd   (   56): Received Set Clipboard
D/Genymotion(   56): Received Set Clipboard
D/dalvikvm(  379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 717K, 13% free 6011K/6864K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 10ms
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -1
W/PluginManager( 1116): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Media.startRecordingAudio blocked the main thread for 10037ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
I/MPEG4Writer(  401): setStartTimestampUs: 10031588
I/MPEG4Writer(  401): Earliest track starting time: 10031588
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
```

This is the logs I got from emulator while stop the recording:

```
 I/MPEG4Writer(  401): Received total/0-length (42/0) buffers and encoded 42 frames. - audio
    I/MPEG4Writer(  401): Audio track drift time: 0 us
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): Stopping Audio track source
    E/genymotion_audio(  401): get_next_buffer() pcm_read error -16
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): Audio track stopped
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): Stopping writer thread
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): 0 chunks are written in the last batch
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): Writer thread stopped
    I/MPEG4Writer(  401): The mp4 file will not be streamable.
    D/MPEG4Writer(  401): Stopping Audio track
    D/AudioPlayer( 1116): renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording.3gp to /storage/emulated/0/../Documents/undefined-.wav
    E/AudioPlayer( 1116): FAILED renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording.3gp to /storage/emulated/0/../Documents/undefined-.wav
    W/PluginManager( 1116): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Media.stopRecordingAudio blocked the main thread for 135ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

Here is my home.ts code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform, Page, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MediaPlugin} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    private _platform: Platform;
    private _fileRecord: MediaPlugin;
    private _pathFile: string;
    private _nameFile: string;
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform) {
     this._platform = platform;
  }
  public startRecord(): void {
     this._pathFile = this.getPathFileRecordAudio();
     this._fileRecord = new MediaPlugin(this._pathFile);
     this._fileRecord.startRecord();
  }

  public stopRecord(): void {
     this._fileRecord.stopRecord();
  }

  private startPlay(): void {
     this._fileRecord = new MediaPlugin(this._pathFile);
     this._fileRecord.play();
  }

  private getPathFileRecordAudio(): string {
     let path: string = (this._platform.is('ios') ? '../Library/NoCloud/': '../Documents/');
     return path + this._nameFile + '-' + '.wav';
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the comments in the [source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/media/index.ts) for the plugin? There are notes about how to tweak things... Someone had something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223253/recording-and-playing-back-audio-on-ionic-3/45243733#45243733) but you gave far more details pertaining to the errors. (And I copied the comments into that answer).